# Error while running standalone app example in python using spark

Tags: python, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am just getting started on spark and am running it on standalone mode over amazon EC2 instance. I was trying examples mentioned in the documentation and while going through this example called Simple App I keep getting this error:
NameError: name 'numAs' is not defined

```
from pyspark import SparkContext

logFile = "$YOUR_SPARK_HOME/README.md"  # Should be some file on your system
sc = SparkContext("local", "Simple App")
logData = sc.textFile(logFile).cache()

numAs = logData.filter(lambda s: 'a' in s).count()
numBs = logData.filter(lambda s: 'b' in s).count()

print "Lines with a: %i, lines with b: %i" % (numAs, numBs)
```

How do I integrate an editor into spark instead of using this dynamic python shell? Why do I keep getting this error?

Thanks for any help/guidance.

Comment: The program runs fine when copied verbatim. How are you invoking the program.

Answer (score 1):

put your all your python code in a **.py file**, then submit the **.py file** like below:

```
# Run a Python application on a Spark Standalone cluster
./bin/spark-submit \
  --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 \
  examples/src/main/python/pi.py \
  1000
```

read here:

[Submitting Applications](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html)

try these examples, really helping:

- https://spark.apache.org/examples.html
- https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/master/examples/src/main/python